# jQuery Fullcalendar: Disable Event Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, gridview, fullcalendar

My Full Calendar looks at the moment like this:
[Screen Fullcalendar before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvy6U.png)

Is it possible to disable the Grid feature, so that the events are displayed without gaps. For example, like this:

[Screen Fullcalendar after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8giYX.png)

Current Code:

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            right: 'title'
        },
        currentLangCode: 'de',
        lang: 'de',
        buttonIcons: true,
        weekNumbers: true,
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: false,
        firstDay: 1,
        height: 'auto',
        events: {
            url: 'ajax/ajax.get_events.php?simulate_user=<?=$_SESSION['admin']['simulate_user'];?>'
        },
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            if(calEvent.project_id != 0)
                window.open('projects.php?uid='+calEvent.project_id, '_blank');
        },
        eventAfterRender:  function (event, element) {
            if(event.time > 0)
            {
                var maxHeight = 1000;
                var minHeight = element.outerHeight();
                var height = event.time / 1.5;

                if(height > maxHeight) height = maxHeight;
                if(height < minHeight) height = minHeight;

                $(element).height(height);
            }
        },
        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.find('.fc-title').html(event.title);

        },
        hiddenDays: [0]
    });
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the gaps are a result of the height manipulation you are doing in the eventAfterRender callback. In month view, events do stack without gaps.  Is there a reason for changing the height?